# "Unexpected end" error

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a Ruby recursive function, but I am getting this error continuously. My code goes something like this

```
def myfun(mylist)
   nextlist = []  

   if mylist.size == 1  
      return (mylist[0])
   else
      # populate the list "nextlist" with fewer elements as compared to mylist somehow
   end

   return myfun(nextlist)
end
```

The following error message comes up pointing at the last `end` statement:

> syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end

Where is the problem here?

Comment: This snippet looks okay. You'll need to post the entire module.

Comment: It looks ok but there's an indentation problem. try ruby -w to give you warnings about these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the old "teach a man to fish" proverb, I'll answer the more general question "how do I find a missing or superfluous `end`?".

For this, I find it very helpful to use the auto-indenting feature of my editor. In vim, I just hit gg=G to indent the entire file, and scan through it visually to find where the indent starts being different from what I'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the syntax error when I copy and paste your code. Is there other code around your pasted function that might be missing an `end`?

Comment: Sorry,but I am not supposed to copy paste my code in here. Its against the honor code.

Comment: If the snippet you gave wasn't copied directly from your project, then perhaps you are missing a `end` in the recursive function in your actual project. Otherwise I would check for a missing `end` in the code located before your recursive function.